# Tab-off ui-bootstrap typeahead only when row is explicitly selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've created this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/livuqafe/2/edit) to demonstrate the issue I'm having.  If you go here, try type "Five" and move on.  Your natural reaction would be to type "Five" and then press tab, and if you wanted "Five-Hundred," you'd arrow-down once; however, in this case, you have to type "Five" and then either press escape or physically mouse out of the box without clicking any of the other options

So, basically, when you're using typeahead, if there is at least one matching result for your current criteria, pressing tab will select it.  My expected behavior is that as you type, the current selected option is exactly what you're typing, and if you want one of the other results you must down-arrow one or more times.

Here is the code that's in the jsBin:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <div>
    {{selected}}
  </div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="item for item in typeaheadOptions | filter:$viewValue">
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.typeaheadOptions = [
    'One','Two','Three','Four','Five-Hundred','Fifteen','Fourteen','Fifty','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten'
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up modifying `ui-bootstrap` to work how I want it to.

I added a `mustMouseDownToMatch` property/attribute to the directive, like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="item for item in typeaheadOptions | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-mouse-down-to-match="true">
```

And the javascript:

```
var mustMouseDownToMatch = originalScope.$eval(attrs.typeaheadMouseDownToMatch) ? originalScope.$eval(attrs.typeaheadMouseDownToMatch) : false;
```

I also added this function which will put the current text into the first item of the typeahead list, and make it the selected item:

```
var setFirstResultToViewValue = function (inputValue) {
    scope.matches.splice(0, 0, {
        id: 0,
        label: inputValue,
        model: inputValue
    });

    // set the selected item to the first item in the list, which is this guy
    scope.activeIdx = 0;
}
```

And that is called in the `getMatchesAsync` call in the typeahead directive:

```
var getMatchesAsync = function(inputValue) {
// do stuff
    $q.when(parserResult.source(originalScope, locals)).then(function(matches) {
        // do stuff
        if (matches.length > 0) {
             // do stuff
        }
        if (mustMouseDownToMatch) {
            setFirstResultToViewValue(inputValue);
        }
        // do stuff
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

A more recent way to do this since I ran into the same issue and maybe wasn't available back then.
[image]

You can add this now as an attribute

```
typeahead-should-select="$ctrl.typeaheadShouldSelect($event)"
```

In your controller or custom component add the following which will allow you to tab now and also if you tab over the item you can press enter to select it.

```
 self.typeaheadShouldSelect = function($event) {
                if ($event.key === 'Tab') {
                    var e = $.Event('keydown');
                    e.which = 40;
                    $($event.currentTarget).trigger(e);
                }
                if ($event.key === 'Enter') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
```